# How can integrate zend module with wordpress admin dashbord

Tags: plugins, php

I want to add zend application into wordpress admin dashbord with a menu link.I have copy all the application folder files from zend application and create a plugin in wordpress,its working when we will access index page,but when we will access other link like add/edit of index page of zend plugin,its not working.